# JavaFX TableView adding extra column for same data

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-tableview

I have a small app. With this app, I can add a new Employee record to a MySQL database and then display these records. `buildData()` retrieves data from the database and displays it in the TableView, I also call this method every time a new record is added to "refresh" the TableView. This however isn't behaving as expected.

This is the view after the first record is added:

[image]

when I hit the button to add another record, this is what I get:

[image]

If I close the app and reopen it, the TableView is normal:

[image]

This is what the `buildData()` method looks like (Method ignores Typechecking and all that.Probably the cause?)

```
private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;

public void buildData() {
    Connection c;
    TableColumn col;
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {

        c = DataBaseConnection.connectToDatabase();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM employees";

        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {

            final int j = i;
            col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });
            employeeTableView.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }
        while (rs.next()) {

            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        employeeTableView.setItems(data);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
}
```

and then the method to add a new Employee Record to the database:

```
 public void addEmployeeToDatabase() {

    Employee employee = new Employee("Anne Droid", "Marketing", "Gender");

    String query = "INSERT INTO employees (Employee_Name, Department, Gender) VALUES (?, ? , ?)";

    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, employee.getEmployeeName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, employee.getDepartment());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, employee.getGender());
        preparedStatement.execute();

        buildData();
        connection.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally, the Employee class:

```
public class Employee {

private StringProperty employeeName;
private StringProperty department;
private StringProperty gender;

public Employee() {

}

public Employee(String employeeName, String department, String gender) {
    this.employeeName = new SimpleStringProperty(employeeName);
    this.department = new SimpleStringProperty(department);
    this.gender = new SimpleStringProperty(gender);
}

public String getEmployeeName() {
    return employeeName.get();
}

public StringProperty employeeNameProperty() {
    return employeeName;
}
...
```

Am using pure java, no FXML.I've searched for a solution, but none is available (As far as I can tell).
Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `buildData` method you replace the items. However you add new `TableColumn`s to the `columns` list without removing any columns. This way the number of columns is increased every time you call the `buildData` method.

Clear the `columns` list before adding new columns to fix this:

```
...

ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

employeeTableView.getColumns().clear();

for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {

    final int j = i;
    col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));

    ...

    employeeTableView.getColumns().add(col);
}

...
```

Comment: Yup!. That did it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the table columns every time you create them so that they don't repeat again.

col.getColumns().clear();

Comment: Hi Farshid, welcome to stackoverflow. Before answering a question, please read the question and all answers already posted. Your answer is just (a short) duplicate of fabian's answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).